# No image entry in Prestashop Web Service when creating new product

Tags: php, image, curl, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

So, as I am specifying in the title, I am using Prestashop Web Service to add products to my shop. Everything is easy and beautiful with it. I managed to easily add new products to the shop with combinations, categories etc.
The problem arises when adding images.

PS's documentation shows how to send images to the API so they will link with the product. For example, if I have a product with ID 150, then using CURL with POST to send an image to /api/images/products/150 will add that image to the product [*(see here)*](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+9+-+Image+management).
My issue is as follows: when I create a new product using the PS Web Service API, it returns me the XML containing info about the new product. Let's say that my product ID is 151. When going to /api/images/products the last entry there is 150. So basically adding a new product doesn't add a new entry in the images/products section of the API, so I have nowhere to send the image via CURL.
I couldn't find a solution on the internet until now. Does anyone know how to force the webservice to create a /images/products entry with the new product id, or how can I manually create an entry? Any help is appreciated. If further details are needed, please write in the comments and I will add them.

PS: I am using PS v1.6

Comment: same issue here, and i didn't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a way to add an image to a product that has NO image (no entry is found in `/api/images/products/{ID}`). 
The key is creating a new CurlFile rather than just sending the binary of the image back to the PS WS. You can use the following function:

```
/**
* Function that creates a new Product Feature Value and returns its newly created id
* @param product_id = the id of the product for which the image should be uploaded
* @param image_name = the String containing the name of the downloaded image (which will be found in /img)
* @return the ID of the newly inserted image
*/
function addNewImage( $product_id, $image_name  ) {
    $url = PS_SHOP_PATH . '/api/images/products/' . $product_id;
    $image_path = 'img/'. $image_name;
    $key = PS_WS_AUTH_KEY;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data','Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => new CurlFile($image_path)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
}
```

I hope this helps people who went through the same problem as I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function, using cURL:

```
function addProductImage($ProductId, $ImageUrl){
    $url = $this->url.'api/images/products/'.$ProductId;
    /**
     * Uncomment the following line in order to update an existing image
     */
    //$url = 'http://myprestashop.com/api/images/products/1/2?ps_method=PUT';


    if(class_exists('CURLFile')) {
        $cfile = new CURLFile(realpath($ImageUrl));
        //$cfile->setPostFilename("image.jpg");
    }
    else
        $cfile = '@'.realpath($ImageUrl);


    $postFields = array(
        'image' => $cfile,

    );


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:multipart/form-data','Expect:'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true); //edit
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $this->key.':');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    return $result;

}


$this->addProductImage(1, '/path/image/test.jpg');
```

Comment: icy2k thank you for your answer. Question: doesn't this code do the same thing as the one I linked before, from the PS documentation? See here, at the bottom of the page: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+9+-+Image+management

Comment: Yes, but try adding HTTPHEADER like this example. I've tried this now and it's works for me. Can you show me your error?

Comment: I just tried to add the header, and still same thing. If I dump result, it just prints `bool(false)`. Also if I write the error output of curl to a file, it looks like this: `* Hostname was found in DNS cache
*   Trying IP...
* Connected to domain.com (IP) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'KEY'
* Connection #0 to host domain.com left intact` which is not useful for debugging. If for example I add an image manually to the newly created product, I can use the above code with no issue whatsoever...